# Adjust date's timezone so that hour is accurate (doesn't just add offset at the end)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2017

Difficult to word but easy to show:

```
select getutcdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
^ returns 2018-11-30 01:13:30.293 +00:00

select getutcdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US Eastern Standard Time'
^returns 2018-11-29 20:13:30.293 -05:00
```

Instead of the adjusted localtime format above I need it to print:

```
2018-11-29 15:13:30.293  (hour adjusted - no offset)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select getutcdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 

select getutcdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US Eastern Standard Time'

select CONVERT(datetime2, getutcdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US Eastern Standard Time', 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AT TIME ZONE returns a [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) value.

You could either cast it to another DateTime type, or (in most cases better) do the formatting client-side.